# Extract data JSON response with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I wanna know how extract data (building a Scrapy Spider) from a json source. The feed is http://demoledores.easy.com.ar/products/productos.json

Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on how to do this on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the response being in JSON it, makes job further easier.

//get response
import json

def parse(self, response):
    json_data = json.loads(response.body)

then you can iterate over dictionary get what you want.